# Integrated graphics faster than NVidia graphics in QtQuick

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

I use QtQuick to create my application.
But I found that the preformance is better when I run the application by integrated graphics.
About 40 fps by integrated graphics but 20 fps by NVidia graphics on the same operations.

Qt version:5.9.5
My computer is ThinkPad X1 Extreme(with NVidia 1050Ti Max-Q).

Does anyone know the reason?
Has any way to solve it?

Comment: More info needed. How do you run your app? Which opengl module do you use? desktop, software, angle?

Comment: Should desktop I thought.No default settings have been changed.

Comment: Not obviously. Read Graphics Drivers section in this doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html and try to set different OpenGL modules with QCoreApplication::setAttribute https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#setAttribute

Comment: I tried.Still integrated graphics better in all three module.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Nvidia MX330) I found that in order to activate GPU performance, I needed to raise the GPU max temperature.  The default max temperature (see `nvidia-smi -q -d TEMPERATURE` or `nvidia-settings -q GPUMaxOperatingTempThreshold`) was 57°C, which is the standard operating temperature.  To get better performance a higher temperature needs to be permitted (allowing the GPU to run at higher power).

On a linux system the max temperature can be set using the acpi_call kernel module (acpi-call-dkms on debian/ubuntu). Once acpi_call is activated (`modprobe acpi_call`), then high performance (higher GPU max temperature) can be activated with

```
# echo '\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q6D' > /proc/acpi/call >/dev/null
```

which raises the GPU max temperature throttle to 87°C. Instructions for this are given at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T14/T14s_(Intel)_Gen_1#Power_modes with discussion at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/severe-throttling-on-thinkpad-t14-gen-1-with-geforce-mx330/177366/1

You could also check your Nvidia GPU is configured to run in performance mode in the Nvidia config app (nvidia-settings).